# Simplest way to set up an Ethereum DApp development environment On Ubuntu 14.04 including a Client, and IDE and test environment

Tags: dapp-development, clients, testing, ubuntu, ide

**What is the simplest way to set up an Ethereum DApp development environment on Ubuntu 14.04 including a Client, and IDE and test environment?**

I'm basing this Client-IDE-Test configuration on the suggestions [here](https://dappsforbeginners.wordpress.com/tutorials/setting-up-your-development-environment/):

> Firstly, download the latest stable binary of Alethzero, our C++
>   client, and install on your chosen operating system. If you experience
>   problems with the stable build then you may wish to switch to the
>   latest cutting edge version, which may ameliorate some of your issues.
>   If you choose instead to build your own then build instructions are
>   here.
>
> Secondly, Install MIX our integrated development environment available
>   for Windows and Mac here. If you are using Linux follow the
>   instructions here to install mix also.
>
> Finally, make sure you install Mist to test your Dapps and fine-tune
>   your front-ends as you develop them.

*It seems as if significant development has taken place since this was written - with everything being combined in the [webthree umbrella repository](https://github.com/ethereum/webthree-umbrella)?*

I'm hoping the answer will be as simple as

```
sudo apt-get Ethereum-dapp-development-stuff
```

though that may be wishful thinking...

Answer (score 3):

Try using [Truffle](http://truffle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/installation/) framework, with geth which you can install using `apt-get install ethereum`. check out truffle link for installation documentation.

Also there's the [browser-solidity](http://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/#version=soljson-latest.js) web IDE, which is alright.